# Is it necessary to declare abstract method in java if class is abstract

Tags: java

If we declare method as abstract then class by default becomes abstract .Then can we apply this vice versa .

Comment: You could just try it...

Comment: It would have been faster to test yourself than post it here...

Answer (score 6):

> If we declare method as abstract then class by default becomes abstract .

[This statement is wrong.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1) If you try to declare an `abstract` method in a `class` that is not declared `abstract`, you will get a compilation error.

If you declare a class as `abstract`, then you've declared the class as abstract. It need not have any `abstract` methods.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be applied vice-versa, as an abstract class also can have concrete methods.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the Sotirios answer, abstract class not need abstract methods and if you want an abstract method, you will need turn this method abstract, declaring it.

if a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract.